# Undefined X Axis Labels for line chart Apexcharts

Tags: angular, apexcharts

I have an app that pushes data into the chart series through api calls. on the second updateseries(), x axis labels do not show up for some of the data.

Here is a link to codesandbox with the issue reproduced, you can view and edit the code by clicking the open sandbox button
sandbox - https://zr4mpt.csb.app/

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild("chart") chart: ChartComponent;
  public chartOptions: Partial<ChartOptions>;

  constructor() {
    this.chartOptions = {
      series: [],
      chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: "line",
        zoom: {
          enabled: false
        }
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      stroke: {
        curve: "smooth"
      },

      grid: {
        row: {
          colors: ["#f3f3f3", "transparent"], // takes an array which will be repeated on columns
          opacity: 0.5
        }
      },
      xaxis: {}
    };
  }

  updateChart(num) {
    let series1: any = [
      {
        name: "D",
        data: [
          {
            x: "Tue",
            y: "0"
          },
          {
            x: "Thu",
            y: "46460"
          }
        ]
      }
    ];

    let series2: any = [
      {
        name: "D",
        data: [
          {
            x: "Tue",
            y: "0"
          },
          {
            x: "Thu",
            y: "46460"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "A",
        data: [
          {
            x: "Mon",
            y: "100000"
          },
          {
            x: "Tue",
            y: "500000"
          },
          {
            x: "Wed",
            y: "14681200"
          },
          {
            x: "Thu",
            y: "2046460"
          },
          {
            x: "Fri",
            y: "4240000"
          }
        ]
      }
    ];

    switch (num) {
      case 1:
        this.chart.updateSeries(series1);
        break;
      case 2:
        this.chart.updateSeries(series2);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add some code here in question.

Comment: @PankajParkar I have linked a codesandbox with my issue reproduced

Comment: Yes I understand, My thought is, it becomes easier to look at code easily without opening a link. And decide whether they have any clue about the question or not.

Comment: How can one help you with the issue if you don't put codes here? Sandbox only shows what you are getting as output not how. Put the relevant code in the Q please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.